# Ugly bash function to send commands and "say" anything in screen over ssh. Is there a better way?

Tags: bash, ssh, gnu-screen, function

I’m working on a function this works but it is ugly.  One thing that could be changed is being able to know the name of the screen.  Using screen -dms minecraft java ….jar now starts a screen session named with what appears to be random numbers..hostname.  Next is the voodoo that happens to strip the name from screen -ls and use it.  Then there is awk.  There has to be a better way.

```
say_this()
{
    REEN="$(ssh -p 8989 192.168.1.101 screen -ls)"
    echo $REEN > log/log.txt
    AWK="$(awk 'FNR == 1 { print $6 }' log/log.txt)"
    NAME="$(echo $AWK)"
    echo $1
    ssh -p 8989 192.168.1.101 screen -S $NAME -p 0 -X stuff \"$1^M\"
}

say_this "say test"
say_this "say !@#$%^&*()<>?This string should work!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a lot of variables and a log file unnecessarily.

I'm not sure about the stuff after `stuff`, but I bet it can be simpler:

```
say_this()
{
    local name="$(ssh -p 8989 192.168.1.101 screen -ls | awk 'NR==2 {print $1}')"
    echo "$1"
    ssh -p 8989 192.168.1.101 screen -S "$name" -p 0 -X stuff "$1"
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much!  Not ugly anymore.

Comment: Also I had to change "$1" to \"$1^M\" for it to work.